# calling a mothod into a fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have an edit text in an activity and I want to set my edit text's size in another fragment like `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I don't know what I should do?

This is my fragment:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

       public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
     }
}
```

This is my activity:

```
public class firstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edittext1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fist);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_1_id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an eventbus to send data from activity to fragment

Fragment

```
  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implement sendEdittextSize {

  public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  public void onMessageEvent(CountEvent event) {
  int count = event.getCount();
  }    

  }
```

Activity

```
  public class firstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText edittext1;
  SendEdittextSize sender;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_fist);

     sender = this;
     editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_1_id);
     getCount();

 }

  public void getCount(){

  EventBus.getDefault().post(new editText.getText().toString().length());

  }

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

   }

}
```